# CORS headers not showing up in my request/response on Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-cors-headers

I've made the following CORS implementation on my Django project using django-cors-headers.

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = []

MIDDLEWARE = [
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
....
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
    'corsheaders',
]
```

For some reason, I don't see the effect of these headers (I don't have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in my headers). I print out the request and response headers in my view. This is my view:

```
def payment(request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request.headers)
    params_in = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    headers_in = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer key,
        }
    response = requests.post('https://url.com/v1/endpoint', 
            headers=headers_in,
            data=params_in)

    resp_out = Response(response.json()['value'])
    print(resp_out.headers)
    return resp_out
```

My request headers are `['Host', 'Connection', 'Content-Type', 'Origin', 'Accept-Encoding', 'Cookie', 'Accept', 'User-Agent', 'Referer', 'Accept-Language', 'X-Request-Id', 'X-Forwarded-For', 'X-Forwarded-Proto', 'X-Forwarded-Port', 'Via', 'Connect-Time', 'X-Request-Start', 'Total-Route-Time', 'Content-Length']` and my only `resp_out` header is `'Content-Type'`.

Why could this be? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You don't receive the CORS headers as a part of the request rather the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: Your_Origin_Name`(if among the allowed ones mentioned in CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = []
) header will be sent back as a response header.