# Django Cors Handler evaluating to false but not rejecting API requests

Tags: django, django-views, django-signals, django-cors-headers

My Django Cors Framework Handler is being ran, but is not filtering anything out. When I inserted print statements to the handlers, I saw that the value was evaluating to false (meaning it had the signal to reject) but it was not actually filtering out requests to my view endpoint. I did not make any changes to my view (I was under the assumption I did not need to). Am I missing something that will make it reject requests that don't meet the criteria in `cors_allow_mysites`.

`handlers.py`

```
from corsheaders.signals import check_request_enabled

def cors_allow_mysites(sender, request, **kwargs):
    return ("Origin" in request.headers) and (request.headers["Origin"] == 'url.com')

check_request_enabled.connect(cors_allow_mysites)
```

`apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class ApiEndpointConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'api_endpoint'

    def ready(self):
        # Makes sure all signal handlers are connected
        from . import handlers  # noqa
```

`__init__.py`

```
default_app_config = "api_endpoint.apps.ApiEndpointConfig"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CORS headers not showing up in my request/response on Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72849880/cors-headers-not-showing-up-in-my-request-response-on-django)

Comment: @GracenOwnby no, this question has to do with handlers/signals